# После создания recyclerView на моем телефоне при запуске ошибка

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

После создания recyclerView на моем телефоне при запуске ошибка. А на емуляторе работает. Я думаю что проблема в версии recyclerView. Подскажите пжалуйста.

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.regestration/com.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:64)
    at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:918)
    at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:419)
    at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
Aborted 

Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: Вы непонимаете принципа работы нашего сайта. Ваша проблема ничем не важнее прочих. Не стоит пытаться обмануть систему удаляя плохо сформулированный вопрос и создавая аналогичный новый. Вам надо предоставлять в вопросе больше информации - что вы делали, что вы пробовали, привести ссылку на предыдущий вопрос с кратким описанием ваших ответов на вопросы под ним. То как вы сейчас действуете - не эффективно и так вы врятли дождётесь ответа. По сути - попробуйте на другом телефоне. Возможно у вас какая-то особенная модель или лаунчер

Comment: извините, етот телефон до создания recycler отлично работал с android studio. А сейчас ошибка, но когда открываю в емуляторе то все работает. Через телефон просто быстрее тестить.

Comment: Судя по гуглу проблема реально может быть в модели телефона или установленном на нём лаунчере. У вас какая-то очень специфическая проблема и вы никак не помогаете её решить повторяя уже сказанное в ответ на конкретное предложение

Comment: У меня нет больше телефона, только один.

Comment: А модель-то какая? Вы сильно снижаете вероятность получить помощь тем, что ответы из вас клещами тянуть надо. У вас ASUS ZenPhone и ОС версии 5+?

Comment: Попробуйте полностью удалить из телефона созданное вами приложение и заново попробовать из android studio, чтоб приложение переустановилось с нуля.

Comment: да, asus. Что ето значит ?

Comment: После того как удалил не могу наззад поставить приложение. Но уже другая ошибка.

Comment: @Fedia, ваши сообщения удивительно неинформативны. Что и как удалили что за ошибка совершенно не ясно. Попробую аналогию - вы когда-нибудь пробовали бабушке по телефону объяснить как скайпом пользоваться? Что вы чувствовали когда она говорила "ничего не работает"?

Comment: ошибку я обновил сразу еще.

Comment: @Fedia, попробуйте это решение: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24241687/3212712.

Comment: @Fedia, и не надо менять вопрос по ходу выяснения проблемы. Если заявленная в вопросе проблема исчезла после применения чего-то из ответов то надо принять ответ и, если появилась новая проблема - задать новый вопрос. Либо дополнить текущий вопрос новой информацией. Так работает наш сайт - одна проблема - один вопрос.

Comment: @Fedia, когда вам отвечают на вопрос в комментариях не следует вопрос удалять - вопросы - общее достояние пользователей сайта. Наш сайт - не место где решают вашу конкретную проблему, а место сбора БД практических решений проблем. Ваши действия, согласно правилам сайта - вандализм. Вам следовало попросить из комментов в ответ перенести решение либо самому написать ответ. Удалять не надо. Я про этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620487/e-androidruntime-fatal-exception-main

Answer (score 1):

Варианты, которые могут решить вашу проблему (сперва отключите телефон от ПК):

**Вариант 1**
Зайдите в Настройки->Для разработчиков и удостоверьтесь, что не выбрано никакое приложение для отладки. Если выбрано уберите.

**Вариант 2**
Зайдите в Настройки->Для разработчиков и выключите проверку приложения полученного по USB

**Вариант 3**
Закройте все сторонние приложения, которые включены сейчас, чтоб освободить как можно больше ОЗУ и попробуйте заново.

**Вариант 4**
Если установлени нестандартный ланчер попробуйте удалить его и/или установите ланчер от гугла и попробуйте заново.

Одно из вышеперечисленных решений помогало тем, кто имел такие же проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по гуглу проблема в девайсе определённого производителя - это значит что производитель вашего телефона плохо написал софт к нему. Вам теперь придётся всячески извращаться чтобы работать с ним. Если обновлений системы для него нет или они не помогают, то можно попробовать такие извращения -

1. Перед запуском смахивать из диспетчера задач все (вообще все) приложения и/или сделать `force stop` вашему.
2. Ставить приложение через [терминал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230530/3212712)
3. Добавить задачу при сборке для [прибития приложения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30580005/3212712)
4. Аналогичные хаки из гугла по запросу ошибки.